# Is there a way to include the document creation time with XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdf, isodate

I'm currently using `\isodate{\today} \currenttime}` to include an aproximate creation time for a XeTeX document. This is "good enough" but doesn't include the timezone. In pdflatex the creation time of a document can be included with `\pdfcreationdate`, is there an equivalent command that works with XeTeX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by running an external program, for example, `date` on Unix systems. The output can be redirected to a file and then read by TeX.
On Unix systems, also piping is possible.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\immediate\write18{date >\jobname.date}

\begin{document}
Current time is: \input{\jobname.date}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The shell escape feature can be enabled by command line option `-shell-escape` (TeX Live) or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX).

Comment: For Windows users, use `\immediate\write18{date /t >\jobname.date}`.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm converting documents with `pandoc` (which doesn't yet have support for `--latex-engine-opt`) so was hoping to avoid anything that needs specific flags.

Comment: @nikgaffney In my answer I have listed the officially documented option names. They work regardless of the compiler (also in TeX, pdfTeX, LuaTeX). Nowadays, TL15 and MiKTeX seems to support each other option names: `--enable-write18` and `--shell-escape` can both be used.

Comment: @nikgaffney Without the shell escape feature, the time resolution is date and time in minutes (`\time`) without time zone in XeTeX. But you can modify your build process to run the `date` command just before the `pandoc`  command to generate the file with the full date inclusive time zone.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use features provided by your editor.  In case of `emacs`, you can use `time-stamp`.  First, you have to adjust the variables `time-stamp-format` and `time-stamp-pattern`.  I suggest using file local versions by putting something like this at the end of your document:

```lisp
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% eval: (set (make-local-variable 'time-stamp-format) "%3a %02d/%02m/%4y %02H:%02M:%02S %Z")
%%% eval: (set (make-local-variable 'time-stamp-pattern) "\\\\newcommand{\\\\timestamp}{%%}")
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Next, you put the following in the first line of your document:

```
\newcommand{\timestamp}{}
```

followed by the rest of your LaTeX code.  Each time you save your document, `emacs` automatically updates the argument of `\timestamp` and you can use the command in your document, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\timestamp}{Don 21/05/2015 23:05:25 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{Last saved: \timestamp}
\end{document}
```

is the result on my box.

Comment: Thanks. it's a nice idea, but i was hoping to find something built in. The `--shell-escape` method or modifying the build process (as mentioned by @heiko-oberdiek above) fit a little better with the automated process i'm currently working with.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a package `Datetime`. This seems to print the time zone too.
Using the command `\DTMnow`

Refer to http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved if you provided a full working example, starting with `\documentclass`, which shows your point.

Comment: The package `datetime2` supports seconds and time zone in case of pdfTeX, because pdfTeX provides this information in `\pdfcreationdate`. In case of XeTeX the package only provides the date and the time without seconds and time zone.